# Serial port for Arduino in Mac

Tags: arduino, serial-port, driver, arduino-uno, usbserial

I could not select the serial port in my Arduino IDE. It is greyed out even if I connect my USB to serial cable. What is the proper driver for that and where I can find that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The driver for PL2303HX in Mac is [here](https://www.adafruit.com/images/product-files/954/PL2303_MacOSX_1_6_0_20151022.zip) and in windows is [here](https://www.adafruit.com/images/product-files/954/PL2303_Prolific_DriverInstaller_v1_12_0.zip), which you most probably need. If you need the driver for CP210x USB to UART Bridge VCP (virtual com port), it is [here](https://www.silabs.com/products/mcu/Pages/USBtoUARTBridgeVCPDrivers.aspx).